# Serial port communication in Qt

Tags: qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I am new to Qt and need to prepare a project to send hex commands from rs232.
QString line contains 64bit binary data which i have to convert into hexadecimal and send it through rs232 .

```
 QString a=ui->comboBox->currentText();
    QString s1;
    s1="./calc "+a;
    QProcess p1;
    p1.start(s1);
    p1.waitForFinished(-1);
    QString line ;
     //read
           QFile file("TeleOutput.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         return;
     QTextStream in (&file);
  line = in.readAll();
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(line);
```

So, how to convert 64 bit binary data in QString line to hexadecimal value and transfer it through rs232?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - you should really use [QtSerialPort](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort)

Second of all - `QString` is a class, which works with *actual* string. `QByteArray` works with raw data. When you write `QString line = in.readAll();` it implicitly calls `QString(const QByteArray &ba)`, which uses `QString::fromAscii`.

Last of all, if you want to process 64bit integers, you should do something like this:

```
quint64 d;
QDataStream stream(&file);
while (!stream.atEnd())
{
    stream >> d;
    process(d);
}
```

**Update**

*Quote*:

> My problem is that in plainTextEdit
>   "1111110101000101010101010101010101010101010101010101010......." 64
>   bit data is populated , i need to convert this data into hex and send it through rs232

*Solution*:

```
QString binData = plainTextEdit.toPlainText();
QByteArray result;
while (binData.size() >= 64)
{
    quint64 d;
    QString dataPiece = binData.left(64);
    binData.remove(0, 64);
    d = dataPiece.toULongLong(0, 2);
    result += QByteArray::number(d);
}
_com->write(result);
_com->flush();
```

Where `_com` is a pointer to `QtSerialPort`, with all parameters set and opened without errors.